# Kendo MVVM Binding with Array of primitive values and events

Tags: kendo-mvvm

I have an array of primitive values which I'm binding to a set of inputs. (see link below), I'm facing two main issues.

## First issue:

The view does not sync with the model whenever I edit the input, instead it throws the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: source.set is not a function
>       at init.set (kendo.binder.js:278)

## Second issue:

When I bind an event to a span within the inputs template it throws another error.

> JQuery.Deferred exception: source.get is not a function TypeError:
>   source.get is not a function at subclass.get
>   (webpack:///./node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.binder.js?:301:31)

Here is a link to a DOJO exemple where you can replicate those issues: https://dojo.telerik.com/@houtheyfa/ohIdOlEs

Comment: strange but i have done lot of these, but it doesnt work in DOJO . your code seems to be correct

Comment: I am not getting the error which you are getting, but i get t.get is not a function

Comment: @DashangG.Makwana yeah, actually both errors are the same.
You get t.get / source.get when the framework is trying to bind the array to the view. 
to see the other error try to remove the data-bind="events:{click: removeItem}" from the span, then edit any of the  inputs. its like the kendo framework is not able to map the primitive arrays with their model.  instead it works with Objects array.